# make center stack widget on web screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a stack widget like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: min(580, MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)),
          child: Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              Positioned(top: -20, left: 470, child: ProfileCard(color: Colors.grey, child: Container())),
              ProfileCard(color: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(.1), child: Container()),
              Positioned(
                top: -20,
                left: 20,
                child: ProfileCard(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Container(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but it is not the center of the screen in the web. I also added `alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center` or center widget but it is not located in center of the screen:

[image]

this is ProfileCard:

```
class ProfileCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Color? color;
  const ProfileCard({Key? key, required this.child, this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 480, maxHeight: 700),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        color: color,
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you are using two stack? And can you include `ProfileCard`

Comment: But it still missing `ProfileCard` widget

Comment: this is it's result https://postimg.cc/hhBWwFdx

Comment: Consider including proper snippet that will reproduce the issue, here `ProfileCard` is known, result won't help only code can talk

Comment: I add ProfileCard code,

Comment: Can you include an image you are trying to build

Comment: https://postimg.cc/hhBWwFdx  widget locate in center , that's it

Comment: You can remove `left: 470,`

Comment: I need this widget

Answer (score 0):

The reason you face this issue is that you are set position for your widget and by that you disable stack's alignment for those widget, try this:

```
 Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      width: double.maxFinite,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
        width: double.maxFinite,
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: min(580, MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)),
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: ProfileCard(color: Colors.grey, child: Container()),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 20,
              left: -20,
              child: ProfileCard(
                  color: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(.1), child: Container()),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              child: ProfileCard(color: Colors.white, child: Container()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

and change `ProfileCard` like this:

```
class ProfileCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Color? color;
  const ProfileCard({Key? key, required this.child, this.color})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: min(580, MediaQuery.of(context).size.width) / 2,
          maxHeight: 700),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        color: color,
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

the result would be like this:
[image]

Comment: what is the problem with my answer?

Comment: I had mistake so I fixed that so this is new.I had forgotten to remove 1 stack

Comment: was my answer what you want?

Comment: Your answer not works bro

Comment: I update my answer again check it out.

Comment: you removed this part ` left: 470` and you changed `min(580, MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)`in Profile card. This widget is new and this is not  widget I want to create. but thanks

Comment: In order to achieve what you want you should do two things, first not setting exact position for your card to set them center and the second is set specific width for cards. you can change card width with any size you want but remember it should be half of second Container's width in parents container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout

```
   return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: min(580, MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            //
            scrollDirection : Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                 Stack(
                   children: [
                      ProfileCard(color: Colors.red, child: Container()),
                     Positioned(left:20, bottom:20,child: ProfileCard(color: Colors.grey, child: Container())),
                     
                   ],
                 ),
                
                ProfileCard(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Container(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

if you don't want it to scroll then add physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to the single child scroll view.. If you are trying to give a shadow then I would suggest you to use a container and add decoration to it using box shadow

Comment: I need stack, part of gray widget is under with widget